# Segmentation Fault in ARM glibc

Tags: c++, linux, qt, arm, glibc

When 4 or more processes of following code run over i.MX6 custom board,
Segmentation Fault is occurred in glibc 2.17 library.

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QTimer>
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QByteArray>
#include <QtCore/QHash>

class DebugClassMap : public QHash<int, QString*>
{
public:
    DebugClassMap()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 7000; ++i)
        {
            insert(i, new QString("AAAA"));
        }
    }

    virtual ~DebugClassMap()
    {
        clear();
    }

    void clear()
    {
        for (iterator it = begin(); it != end(); ++it)
        {
             delete it.value();
             it.value() = 0;
        }
        QHash::clear();
    }

    DebugClassMap& operator=(const DebugClassMap& aMap)
    {
        clear();
        for (const_iterator it = aMap.begin(); it != aMap.end(); ++it)
        {
            insert(it.key(), new QString(*(it.value()))/*->clone()*/);
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Application (MUST BE FIRST IN ORDER TO SETUP QT THREAD REGISTERING!)
    QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

    DebugClassMap dbgMap1;
    DebugClassMap dbgMap2;

    while(true)
    {
        dbgMap1 = dbgMap2;
    }

    app.exec();

    return 0;
}
```

Following is back trace of above code.
It looks strange that __libc_malloc() requires to allocate 524 bytes in #3.
However _int_malloc() requires to allocate very huge memory(722898944 bytes) in #2.

722898944 is 0x2b169000 as hex, and it is very similar value with av (0x2b1694d4).
So I think the cause of this issue is in glibc library.

Please tell me how to fix it.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 8297]
malloc_consolidate (av=0x2b1694d4) at malloc.c:4073
4073                unlink(p, bck, fwd);
(gdb) bt
#0  malloc_consolidate (av=0x2b1694d4) at malloc.c:4073
#1  malloc_consolidate (av=0x2b1694d4) at malloc.c:4019
#2  0x2b0a7dd0 in _int_malloc (av=0x2b1694d4, bytes=722898944) at malloc.c:3358
#3  0x2b0aa234 in __libc_malloc (bytes=524) at malloc.c:2859
#4  0x2af55364 in operator new(unsigned int) ()
   from /target//lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x2af5541c in operator new[](unsigned int) ()
   from /target//lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x2acabb24 in QHashData::rehash(int) ()
   from /target/export/QtArm/qt-arm-4.8.2-10sep2013/lib/libQtCore.so.4
#7  0x00008df0 in QHashData::willGrow (this=0x15268)
    at /export/QtArm/qt-arm-4.8.2-10sep2013/include/QtCore/qhash.h:163
#8  0x00009340 in QHash<int, QString*>::insert (this=0x7eb07af4,
    akey=@0x8b36c, avalue=@0x7eb07ac4)
    at /export/QtArm/qt-arm-4.8.2-10sep2013/include/QtCore/qhash.h:761
#9  0x00009194 in DebugClassMap::operator= (this=0x7eb07af0, aMap=...)
    at main.cpp:87
#10 0x00008aec in main (argc=1, argv=0x7eb07c54) at main.cpp:103
```

Comment: If you look at a [`QHash` reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qhash.html) you will see that there are no virtual functions, which means that the class was not designed to be inherited. By inheriting you probably introduce undefined behavior, leading to your crash.

Comment: Virtual functions are only relevant when referencing objects via pointers. If objects are referenced as-is (like he's doing it) the compiler resolves all method calls at... well compile-time.

Comment: I didn't have like your idea that QHash is not designed to be inherited. It looks good point, Joachim, thank you for your comment. But I think cause this crash issue is in glibc library. Because allocation bytes looks overwritten in glibc library. If your suggestion is cause of this issue, Segmentation fault should be occurred in my program or Qt library.